# shiny: keep reactive selectinput selection when switching tab

Tags: r, shiny

I am designing a dashboard, where the selectinput (or pickerinput) will react or change according to the first selection. In addition, I need to use tabset panel to display plots from different datasets in separate tab; therefore, the sidebarpanel will change when switching between tabs. I am running into a problem when I switch to another tab, the selections I made in the previous tab will be reset once I go back to the previous tab.

The code shown below is a simplified version of my code but enough to illustrate my problem. I am pretty sure it has to do with the updatepickerinput but I just don't know how the second selection can be updated based on the first selection in the pickerinput and also keep the selections the same when switching back and forward between tabs

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# Sample dataframe 1
data1 <- data.frame(
  column1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE),
  column2 = sample(letters, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

# Sample dataframe 2
data2 <- data.frame(
  column1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE),
  column2 = sample(letters, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("uioutput")),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("Dataset 1",
                   textOutput("output_text1")),
          tabPanel("Dataset 2",
                   textOutput("output_text2"))
          )
      )
    )
  )

server = shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(
    input$data_1a,
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "data_1b",
                      label = "Select",
                      choices = unique(data1$column2[data1$column1 == input$data_1a])
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$data_2a,
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "data_2b",
                      label = "Select",
                      choices = unique(data2$column2[data2$column1 == input$data_2a])
    )
  )
  
  output$uioutput <- renderUI({
    
    selected_tab <- input$tabs
    
    if (selected_tab == "Dataset 1") {
      
      sidebarPanel(
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "data_1a",
          label = "Select",
          choices = unique(data1$column1),
          multiple = F),
        
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "data_1b",
            label = "Select",
            choices = unique(data1$column2),
            multiple = F)
        )
        
    } else if (selected_tab == "Dataset 2") {
      
      sidebarPanel(
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "data_2a",
          label = "Select",
          choices = unique(data2$column1),
          multiple = F),
        
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "data_2b",
          label = "Select",
          choices = unique(data2$column2),
          multiple = F)
        )
    }
  })
  
  output$output_text1 = renderText({ paste0(input$data_1a, input$data_1b) })
  output$output_text2 = renderText({ paste0(input$data_2a, input$data_2b) })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you avoid re-rendering of `pickerInput`s by defining it in the `ui`, it should be fine.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# Sample dataframe 1
data1 <- data.frame(
  column1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE),
  column2 = sample(letters, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

# Sample dataframe 2
data2 <- data.frame(
  column1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE),
  column2 = sample(letters, 20, replace = TRUE)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs == 'Dataset 1'",
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "data_1a",
            label = "Select",
            choices = unique(data1$column1),
            multiple = F),
          
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "data_1b",
            label = "Select",
            choices = unique(data1$column2),
            multiple = F)
      ),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.tabs == 'Dataset 2'",
                       pickerInput(
                         inputId = "data_2a",
                         label = "Select",
                         choices = unique(data2$column1),
                         multiple = F),
                       
                       pickerInput(
                         inputId = "data_2b",
                         label = "Select",
                         choices = unique(data2$column2),
                         multiple = F)          
      )
      ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Dataset 1",
                           textOutput("output_text1")),
                  tabPanel("Dataset 2",
                           textOutput("output_text2"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(
    input$data_1a,
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "data_1b",
                      label = "Select",
                      choices = unique(data1$column2[data1$column1 == input$data_1a])
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(
    input$data_2a,
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "data_2b",
                      label = "Select",
                      choices = unique(data2$column2[data2$column1 == input$data_2a])
    )
  )
  
  output$output_text1 = renderText({ paste0(input$data_1a, input$data_1b) })
  output$output_text2 = renderText({ paste0(input$data_2a, input$data_2b) })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It seems like it will work. Thank you! I will try your way in my own code.